# A 3-class confusion matrix

Tags: r, cross-validation, k-nearest-neighbour

I am trying to visualize a 3-class confusion matrix for the `iris` data. The things that I performed.

1. Partitioned `iris` into *50% Train, 25% Test, 25% validation*.
2. I used `knn` to determine which is optimal from a set of k values (1,3,5) by Grid search.
3. Based on the winner model (obtained with k=1) I want to predict the performance on its test set with a 25% split.

I'm having to generate/ visualizing the confusion matrix for this 3-class problem. When I compile it throws me error as below:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'Petal.Width' not found
```

Cannot figure out where it went wrong.

Code:

````
library(caret)
library(class)

spec = c(train = .5, test = .25, validate = .25)

byparts = sample(cut(
  seq(nrow(iris)), 
  nrow(iris)*cumsum(c(0,spec)),
  labels = names(spec)
))

res = split(iris, byparts)

addmargins(prop.table(table(byparts)))

classifier = train(form = Species ~ ., data = res$train, method = 'knn', tuneGrid   = expand.grid(k = c(1,3,5)))
classifier

#Confusion Matrix
y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = res$test[-4])
cm = table(res$test[,4], y_pred)
```
````

Comment: Hi, the Species variable, tyhat is the want that you want to remove for making predictions, has index 5, not 4. So you should write

`y_pred = predict(classifier, newdata = res$test[-5])`
`cm = table(res$test[,5], y_pred)`
And it will work

Comment: Oh, a silly mistake thanks for the help. Also, would like to know is there a way to visually plot this confusion matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I an comment the OP asked how to visually plot a 3x3 confusion matrix. There are an aweful lot of alternatives. Some examples (in no way exhaustive) in R to give a starter for your own ideas:

```
#some example data 
confusion <- data.frame(true = iris$Species, predicted = iris$Species)
confusion$predicted[sample.int(150,40)] <- iris$Species[sample.int(150,40)]
str(confusion)




plot(confusion$true, confusion$predicted)
```

[image]

```
plot(table(confusion$true, confusion$predicted))
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(confusion) +
  geom_count(aes(x = true, y = predicted)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,30))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(confusion) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = true, y = predicted), width = .25, height = .25)
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(confusion) +
  geom_count(aes(x = true, y = predicted), color ="lightgrey") +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(0,30)) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x = true, y = predicted), width = .25, height = .25) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(aggregate(confusion, list(confusion$true, confusion$predicted), FUN = length))+
  scale_color_continuous() +
  geom_text(aes(x = Group.1, y = Group.2, label = true, color = true), size = 25) +  
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This was what I pretty much looking for! Appreciate your time and explanations.